# How can I alias a covariant generic type parameter

Tags: scala, covariance, type-alias

The following code does not compile (in Scala 2.11):

```
case class CovariantClass[+R](value: R) {
  type T = R
  def get: R = value
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    println(CovariantClass[String]("hello").get)
  }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error:(4, 8) covariant type R occurs in invariant position in type R of type T
  type T = R
       ^
```

Why can't I alias a covariant type parameter? If I remove the line `type T = R`, the code compiles and prints `hello`, so the alias seems to be the problem. Unfortunately, this means that I cannot create an alias for more complex types, e.g., `type T = List[R]` does not compile either, although `List` is covariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations):

> The right-hand side of a type alias is always in invariant position.

This means that you cannot create the alias `T` and specify a variant type `R` on the right-hand side. The same applies to `List[R]`, because it is also covariant.

You *can*, however provide a type alias with a type parameter:

```
case class CovariantClass[+R](value: R) {
  type T[+R] = List[R]
  def get: R = value
}
```

If you find yourself wanting to alias the type parameter `R`, you should probably just name it something else in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for quoting the scala spec. I agree with renaming `R` instead of aliasing it, but I was fancying having an alias for something like `Either[ReturnValueInCaseOfFailure,R]`. Unfortunately, the work-around you propose makes `T` parameterized, but it's probably the closest I can get to what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

It's forbidden because it would allow a program that isn't correct, that's always the rule. You could rewrite it like this:

```
case class CovariantClass[+R](value: R) {
  type T <: R
  def get: R = value
}
```

As for an example of how it breaks, consider this:

```
case class CovariantClass[+R](value: R) {
  type T = Int
  def get: R = value
  def put(x: T) {}
  def put2(x: R) {}
}
```

Because of how `T` is defined, it is invariant. That means it can be used in places where covariant types cannot, such as seen above. Notice that `put` compiles but `put2` does not.

Comment: Interesting. Though, in this example, `R` should be a lower bound to `T`, for the code to break, right? Also, I don't see how I could break it without introducing a type bound. Is it just a conservative design choice? In any case: Thank you for the example.

Comment: @KuluLimpa I added an example for problems that might arise. It's just the beginnings of an example, to show how this relates to variance issues. If you need more information, look up questions about variance -- there should be examples of why variant types in certain positions are illegal (I know I wrote some before :)).